# What would cause channel entries to no longer parse after an update (2.3.1 to 2.5.3)

Tags: expressionengine

I'm in the process of updating a client's site to the latest version of EE, and while the update went pretty smoothly, `{exp:channel:entries}` tags no longer render anything inside of them, yet I see that the date on the entry is current or a previous date, the status is set to `open`, and yes, `dynamic="no"` was already set. I can't imagine what would cause this, and a database export reveals that all the channel entries are there. The pages aren't completely blank; the templates themselves render without a problem, it's *just* the `{exp:channel:entries}` tags so far.

Is there anything I can do to test against this? Running the query module with:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data "}
    {title}
{/exp:query}
```

returns with a hashed value of `M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr`.

Comment: Have you tried emptying your cache directory? Also maybe try re-uploading all system files for good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after doing some digging, it turned out that when I turned off my extensions, the content showed up. As a result, I tried disabling extensions, one by one until the culprit revealed itself to be Solspace's Supersearch. It was a previous version of the addon, and updating it to the most current version brought everything back!

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever seen that error when Structure was involved.